# How can I compare a radio button selection to a variable value in C#?

Tags: c#, mouseevent

This was an assignment from my textbook for a C# class that I could never get working properly. I searched online and couldn't find an answer. I asked my professor and other students and they either gave me non-answers (debug one issue at a time) or answers to problems I wasn't having. I feel like this must be something super simple that we would have learned in this basic intro class, but I can't figure it out. Here is the exact prompt for reference:

> Create a project named GuessANumber with a Form that contains a guessing
> game with five RadioButtons numbered 1 through 5. Randomly choose one of the
> RadioButtons as the winning button. When the user clicks a RadioButton, display a
> message indicating whether the user is right.
>
> Add a Label to the Form that provides a hint. When the user’s mouse hovers over the
> label, notify the user of one RadioButton that is incorrect. After the user makes a
> selection, disable all the RadioButtons.

I was able to generate the random number, create a label that when moused over reveals one incorrect answer, and once a user clicks on a radio button, it disables the other buttons.

The problem I ran into was trying to compare the radio button clicked to the random number answer.

First I tried to compare the value in the event handlers like this:

```
private void AnswerButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AnswerButton2.Enabled = false;
            AnswerButton3.Enabled = false;
            AnswerButton4.Enabled = false;
            AnswerButton5.Enabled = false;
            if (randomNumber == 1)
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = "Incorrect";
            }
        }
```

I realized I didn't know how to bring the value of randomNumber into the event handler methods. So then, I tried to set up an if/else loop to check which button was selected using the radio button .Checked property. I did this in Form1 where the randomNumber is initialized and assigned so I can check them against each other, and I also tried creating a separate method to run this loop that I passed the randomNumber to. Something like this:

```
if (AnswerButton1.Checked && answer == 1)
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = "Correct";
            }
```

Both of these kind of worked, but they both had the same issue in that the loop runs immediately when the form loads, so it always finds the else value (no button selected) is true. And clicking a button at that point has no effect.

So my question is, how can I check a radio button selection against a value assigned when the program is initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I didn't know how to bring the value of randomNumber into the event handler methods"*

It sounds like you're declaring the random number inside a method, which means it only has scope for that method. Instead, create a class field to store the value, so it's accessible to all the methods in the class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Give our random number class-level scope, so all class methods can access it
    private int randomNumber;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the random number when the form starts
        this.randomNumber = random.Next(1, 6);
    }

    private void AnswerButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnswerButton2.Enabled = false;
        AnswerButton3.Enabled = false;
        AnswerButton4.Enabled = false;
        AnswerButton5.Enabled = false;

        // Now we have access to the random number because it has class-level scope
        if (this.randomNumber == 1)
        {
            ResultLabel.Text = "Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            ResultLabel.Text = "Incorrect";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it. My instinct was that it had to do with where the variable was declared that would make it accessible to all my methods, but I never got it right. I think it's the fact I guess you can declare a variable in the Form1 class, but you can't assign it a value until it's in the Form1() method? I played around with the placement in my program and found that to be the case. The only reason I tried an if/else loop in the Form1() method is because I saw someone looking for a solution to this problem say that was working for them. At least now I understand what my (very simple) problem was.

Comment: It's all about scope. A variable's scope depends on where it's declared. If declared in a `for` loop, it only has scope for the body of the loop. If declared in a method, it's only accessible within the method. If declared as a class field, it's accessible from anywhere inside the class. And if it's declared as a `public` class member, it's accessible from outside the class as well.

Comment: That makes sense, I think it's just working with forms is still new to me so I'm still figuring out how it relates to what I know about just writing console programs (which is still not much), but I see now how the classes and methods are structured in the form.